# Одновременная закачка файла с FTP с разных компьютеров

Tags: ftp

Здравствуйте!

У меня такой вопрос: если к одному и тому же файлу на FTP-сервере одновременно обратиться с разных компьютеров (например, скачать его), то произойдет ли какая-нибудь ошибка?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, если FTP сервер настроен правильно. От настроек зависит.

Comment: В смысле "настроен правильно"? Ftp-сервер можно настроить? Я никогда не слышал, поэтому точно говорить не могу. А если можно настраивать, то как и где, если это, например, хостинг?

Comment: Сложно представить ftp-сервер, где возможны ошибки в такой ситуации.

Comment: Конечно настраивается, там можно задавать порты, пользователей, одновременных закачек одного файла итд... Но если у вас стандартная установка, то не должно быть проблем!

Comment: Да? А на хостингах, как думаете, все стандартно?

Comment: @alexlz, это на меня так слишком частая работа с файловой системой Windows повлияла...

Comment: на хостингах не будет проблем... на хостингах даже разрешается дозакачивать файл.

Comment: Ладно, благодарю за ценную инфу!

Comment: Проблемы будут если одновременно делать upload (или delete/rename) и что-то ещё... @Asen а при чём здесь винды? Всё что вспоминается (из бяк), так то, что в прошлом тысячелетии :) их ftp-сервер докачку не разрешал (а клиент -- тем более). Но это совсем другая история. Да и тысячелетие другое...